# Python Floating point addition test case failing due to precision issue

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, python-unittest

I had an addition function defined in python and when i ran unit test using the python unittest module , floating point addition test case failed. is there any reference to a good python module which handles the floating point arthematic easy.

Appreciate your help in resolving the error in addition function to return till nonzero numbers after the decimal.

I tried to round the result and run the test , and also tried to cast expected result into float.

p3.py

```
def addition(a,b):
    return a + b
```

and unit test cases for the function is defined in p3_test.py

```
import unittest
from  p3 import addition

class TestAddition(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_Addition(self):
        self.assertEqual(addition(2, 3), 5)
        self.assertEqual(addition(0, -1), -1)
        self.assertEqual(addition(-1, 0.99), -0.01)
```

The third test case fails with below error:

```
    self.assertEqual(addition(-1, 0.99), float(0.01))
AssertionError: -0.010000000000000009 != 0.01

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s
```

Expectation it that all test cases should pass

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: I think you have 2 issues. The first one is that - 1 + 0.99 =  - 0.01, and not 0.01.

Comment: Thanks for the catch of -0.01 Brat , i corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

I understand the floating  point representation is the cause of the issue in my case, since i am looking for an appropriate way to solve the unit test for the same. i found a approximation assert method in unittest module which solves the issue.

here is the new piece of code.

```
import unittest
from  p3 import addition

class TestAddition(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_Addition(self):
        self.assertEqual(addition(2, 3), 5)
        self.assertEqual(addition(0, -1), -1)
        self.assertAlmostEqual(addition(-1, 0.99), -0.01, 7)
```